# Dijkstra's Algorithm not optimized enough

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, priority-queue

I was attempting a question on HackerRank-Dijkstra's Shortest Reach 2 and upon submission my programs times out in 3/7 test cases. One of the test cases had 200 nodes and about 2000 connections. Here is my code-

```
  import java.util.Comparator;
  import java.util.PriorityQueue;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;
  import java.io.DataInputStream;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.StringTokenizer;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;



class Node implements Comparator<Node>{
int cost, node;
Node(){}
Node(int node, int cost){
    this.node=node;
    this.cost=cost;
}
@Override
public int compare(Node n1, Node n2){
    if(n1.cost<n2.cost)return -1;
    else if(n1.cost>n2.cost)return 1;
     return 0;
  }
}
   class Solution {
 // Working program using Reader Class
 static int adjmatrix[][];
 static PriorityQueue<Node> pq;
 static boolean visited[];
 static int distance[];
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 static ArrayList<Map<Integer,Integer>> list;


     static class Reader
     {
         final private int BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 16;
         private DataInputStream din;
         private byte[] buffer;
         private int bufferPointer, bytesRead;

         public Reader()
         {
             din = new DataInputStream(System.in);
             buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
             bufferPointer = bytesRead = 0;
         }

         public Reader(String file_name) throws IOException
         {
             din = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file_name));
             buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
             bufferPointer = bytesRead = 0;
         }

         public String readLine() throws IOException
         {
             byte[] buf = new byte[64]; // line length
             int cnt = 0, c;
             while ((c = read()) != -1)
             {
                 if (c == '\n')
                     break;
                 buf[cnt++] = (byte) c;
             }
             return new String(buf, 0, cnt);
         }

         public int nextInt() throws IOException
         {
             int ret = 0;
             byte c = read();
             while (c <= ' ')
                 c = read();
             boolean neg = (c == '-');
             if (neg)
                 c = read();
             do
             {
                 ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
             }  while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9');

             if (neg)
                 return -ret;
             return ret;
         }

         public long nextLong() throws IOException
         {
             long ret = 0;
             byte c = read();
             while (c <= ' ')
                 c = read();
             boolean neg = (c == '-');
             if (neg)
                 c = read();
             do {
                 ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
             }
             while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9');
             if (neg)
                 return -ret;
             return ret;
         }

         public double nextDouble() throws IOException
         {
             double ret = 0, div = 1;
             byte c = read();
             while (c <= ' ')
                 c = read();
             boolean neg = (c == '-');
             if (neg)
                 c = read();

             do {
                 ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
             }
             while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9');

             if (c == '.')
             {
                 while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9')
                 {
                     ret += (c - '0') / (div *= 10);
                 }
             }

             if (neg)
                 return -ret;
             return ret;
         }

         private void fillBuffer() throws IOException
         {
             bytesRead = din.read(buffer, bufferPointer = 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
             if (bytesRead == -1)
                 buffer[0] = -1;
         }

         private byte read() throws IOException
         {
             if (bufferPointer == bytesRead)
                 fillBuffer();
             return buffer[bufferPointer++];
         }

         public void close() throws IOException
         {
             if (din == null)
                 return;
             din.close();
         }
     }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////
 public static void initialize(int n){
    // adjmatrix=new int[n+1][n+1];
     visited=new boolean[n+1];
     distance=new int[n+1];
     list=new ArrayList<>(n+1);
     pq=new PriorityQueue<>(n+1,new Node());
     for(int i=1; i<=n+1; ++i)list.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
     for(int i=0; i<n+1; ++i)distance[i]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 }

     //////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void shortestPath(int s){
       // int length=adjmatrix.length;
        int min_node;
        visited[s]=true;
        distance[s]=0;
        pq.add(new Node(s,0));
        while(!pq.isEmpty()){
            min_node=pq.remove().node;
            visited[min_node]=true;
            updateDistance(min_node);
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
     //Using adjlist
    private static void updateDistance(int s){
        Map<Integer,Integer> current=list.get(s);
       // Iterator itr=current.entrySet().iterator();
       for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry:current.entrySet()){
            int node=entry.getKey();
            int cost=entry.getValue();
            if(!visited[node]){

                    distance[node]=Math.min(cost+distance[s], distance[node]);
                    pq.add(new Node(node,distance[node]));

            }
        }

    }

         ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     public static void main(String []args)throws IOException{
         Reader r=new Reader();
         //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


         int T=r.nextInt(), N, M;
         for(int caseNo=1; caseNo<=T; ++caseNo){
              initialize(3000);
             N=r.nextInt();
             //initialization

             //initialization of adjacecny matrix



             M=r.nextInt();
             //list=new ArrayList<>(N+1);


             for(int j=1; j<=M; ++j){

                     int node1=r.nextInt();
                     int node2=r.nextInt();
                     int distance=r.nextInt();

                     if(list.get(node1).get(node2)!=null){
                         int temp=list.get(node1).get(node2);
                         if(temp<distance)continue;
                     }

                     list.get(node1).put(node2,distance);
                     list.get(node2).put(node1, distance);

             }

             //end of graph initialization as a hybrid of adjmatrix and adjlist

            int s=r.nextInt();
             shortestPath(s);

             for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i)if(i!=s)System.out.print(((distance[i]==Integer.MAX_VALUE)?-1:distance[i])+" ");
             System.out.println();
         }//end of test cases loop[
     }
}
```

So how can I optimize this code?
Here is the link to the question- https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach

Answer (score 4):

#### Reject nodes already visited

Your main loop looks like this:

> ```
> while(!pq.isEmpty()){
>     min_node=pq.remove().node;
>     visited[min_node]=true;
>     updateDistance(min_node);
> }
> ```

Since your code is capable of adding the same node multiple times to the priority queue (with updated costs), you should reject any node that you've already visited, like this:

```
while(!pq.isEmpty()){
    min_node=pq.remove().node;
    if (visited[min_node])
        continue;
    visited[min_node]=true;
    updateDistance(min_node);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it's not a proper implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm if a node that has already been visited can be re-visited.